# Suggested synonym/retag: rename "sorcery" to "magic"

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms, retagging

We have 1 questions tagged [sorcery](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sorcery). It is ALSO tagged [magic](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic).

It seems that there's very little point to have a specific tag for "sorcery" - it's merely a synonym in real English, and no SFF universe makes a clear distinction between the two. In that question it was merely added since there was a definition of the term being asked for.

I proposed to change [sorcery](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sorcery) to be a synonym of [magic](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic).

If you agree, and have >=5 upvotes in [magic](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic), please feel free to up-vote the synonym suggestion here: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/magic/synonyms

If approved, I will take care of minor re-tagging if it will be necessary.

Comment: Nitpick: there are plenty of SF universes that make a clear distinction between the two. But the distinction varies from universe to universe. So as general concepts, they are synonyms. I'll set up the synonym unless someone objects.

Comment: @Gilles - I already set them up (I have enough upvotes). Or do synonyms require Moderator fairy dust on top of regular 4/5  votes?

Comment: You've suggested it, it still requires votes. As usual, moderators have a binding vote.

Comment: @Gilles - Oh. Sorry. Didn't parse your wording correctly.

Comment: @Gilles - Your first comment made me mad curious, so I asked for an example in the main site. If you already had a specific example when writing a comment, please feel free to answer - cheap and easy rep :)

Comment: I gave a couple at the end of my answer to [hard science fantasy stories](http://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/1279/almost-hard-science-fiction-with-magic-or-hard-science-fantasy/1289#1289) on [literature.se].

Answer (score 3):

While there are some distinctions between them in different universes, specifically that Sorcery tends to deal with spirits of some kind, while magic usually doesn't, there are enough similarities where I think it's fine.

As far as tag synonyms go, a person can "tag" a question with Sorcery still, but it will be converted to magic.

Comment: I don't think there are any such general rules. The first example that came to my mind was [Lyndon Hardy's Five Magics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_of_the_Five_Magics) where it's wizardry that involves spirits, and sorcery is mind-to-mind. The second is [Ethshar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varieties_of_magic_in_Ethshar) where sorcery may indirectly involve spirits (but this hasn't been established yet) and theurgy and demonology involve gods and demons.

Comment: @Gilles: Hmmm, guess I haven't read those kinds. Still, I don't doubt that there are differences in different series...

Answer (score -2):

I agree withh Gilles that there is a distinction between the two, and even in real life, people who study sorcery and people who study magic are studying two different things (with some overlap).

I say keep the two tags the way they are. If someone is reading a story that specifically uses "sorcery" as it's mechanism, then someone is going to be confused when they can't use that tag when asking a question.